# EXTJS - float 2 panels and center them

Tags: css, extjs, css-float, center

I'm stuck with something that I imagined would be quiet simple :)

Floating two panels next to each other and keeping them centered. 
The closest I have gotten is to center the panels but ontop of each other.

like so:

```
         _
        |_|
         _
        |_|
```

I'm trying to get

```
         _   _
        |_| |_|
```

This is my file so far

```
Ext.define("App.view.MyWindow", {
extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias:'widget.mywindow',
requires:[
      //this is just a simply panel with html:'abcde"
         'App.view.Portal1'

      ],
items:[{
    xtype:'portal1',
    height:400,
    width:400,
    style:{
        margin: '0 auto',
    }
},{
    xtype:'portal1',
    height:400,
    width:400,
    style:{
        margin: '0 auto',
    }
}]
});
```

Any ideas? All are welcome :) ... thanks in advance

**Update:**
The closest i've come to a "solution" is the following: (however it requires a set width)

```
Ext.define("App.view.MyWindow", {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.mywindow',
    requires:[
             //this is just a simply panel with html:'abcde" with width & height 400
             'App.view.Portal1'

          ],
          layout:'fit',
    items:[{
        layout:{
            type:'vbox',
            align:'center'
        },
        items:[{
            layout:{
                type:'hbox',
            },
            //Set width :(
            width:800,
            items:[{
                xtype:'portal1',
            },{
                xtype:'portal1',
            }]
        }]

    }]
});
```

**Solution**

Thanks to those who commented. Here is a working solution. Dont use `layout:fit` on the wrapper panel

```
Ext.define("App.view.MyWindow", {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.mywindow',
    requires:[
             //this is just a simply panel with html:'abcde" with width & height 400
             'App.view.Portal1'

          ],
    style:{
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    items:[{
        xtype:'portal1',
        style:{
            display:'inline-block'
        }
    },{
        xtype:'portal1',
        style:{
            display:'inline-block'
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS only solution, since I don't know extjs:

Give each panel the appropriate horizontal margins so they don't run together.  Set their width and height as normal.  Then set `display: inline` on the panels as well.  Finally, set the containing element to use `text-align: center`.  You may need to introduce a new container element for this purpose.

Comment: seems to do as it pleases.. extjs doesnt seem to like it. thanks tho

Comment: went back to give your comment another shot. actually... looked like it work :) however with display:inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

Give 'myWindow' an hbox layout. Items that are contained inside will be layed out horizontally.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox

Comment: your actually not far off.. given me an idea any way... by using the vBox and hBox with align setting middle and center

Comment: ah yeah, I should have mentioned to take a look at the config options as well for centering. But if you got it working, great :)